# Unable navigate to new tab on click of mouse middle button/ ctrl+ click in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

Currently i am using angular 1.6 application
 I implemented this code from stackoverflow but this is not solving my solution.

this is my code below

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {

$rootScope.navigate = function($event, to, params) {

    // If the command key is down, open the URL in a new tab
    if ($event.metaKey) {
        var url = $state.href(to, params, {absolute: true});
        window.open(url,'_blank');

    } else {
        $state.go(to, params);
    }

};

});
```

My HTML code

```
<div class="title" data-ng-click="$ctrl.goToDetails($event)" data-ng-bind="$ctrl.config.entryTitle"></div>
```

Controller

```
$state.go('entry-details', { entryId: vm.config.id, query: vm.query });
```

I am new to angular so please suggest how to implement.
it would be better if i get a fiddle.

Comment: What do need exactly to do?

Comment: on press of ctrl+ click i want one of my tile to open in a new browser tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need in your code is: `absolute: false` and call the `function navigate with ng-click`, below is tested example. it works fine:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state,$window) {

    $rootScope.navigate = function($event, to, params) {

        // If the command key is down, open the URL in a new tab
        if ($event.ctrlKey) {
            var url = $state.href(to, params, {absolute: false});
            $window.open(url,'_blank');

        } else {
            $state.go(to, params);
        }

    };

})

<div ng-click="navigate($event, 'StateName', {PARAMS:PARAMS})">ClickMe</div>
```

Comment: This my Html code `<a  class="title" ng-click="navigate($event, 'entry-details', { entryId: $ctrl.config.id, query: $ctrl.query })" data-ng-bind="$ctrl.config.entryTitle"></a>` 
I tried with the above code but  function in my js file is not getting fired.

Comment: try it with empty param: `<a class="title" ng-click="navigate($event, 'entry-details', {})" ></a>`

Comment: Be sure that you remove the Cache when you update js code

Comment: Here is an example which works:http://plnkr.co/edit/PsmkuiaB3lbIsj69garA?p=preview